# What is exact *average* energy released by uranium fission?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

There are many possible decay products for uranium 235 fission.

I'm interested in the *average* value of the energy released (not an order of magnitude : a rather "precise" value of the average)

I know that binding energy of uranium 235 is 7.59 MeV per nucleon.

I know that average binding energy of decay products is 8.5 MeV per nucleon (but I can't get information on the first and second digit)

Various sources on the web claim that average energy released is 200 MeV for total nucleons of uranium 235.
But some claim more, some claim less, etc.
I see that 235 x (8.5 MeV -7.59 MeV)=213 MeV

I'm really interested in the *average* value (not a specific decay chain), and a value that works, that is compatible with the average binding energy of the decay product. For example, 200 MeV could not work since we see from the previous line that this would give 213 MeV.

I can't find a reliable web document that gives a value "that works".

What is exact *average* energy released by uranium fission ?
And what is the exact "average binding energy of decay products" ?

Comment: It is an engineering number, the _exact_ value of which would depend on for example the time frame considered (all the energy released by decay of fission products comes with a delay).

Comment: I believe that since we know the probability distribution of all decay, and we know the energy binding of each nuclei, there is only one average value possible ?

Comment: *(but I can't information with more information on the first and second digit)* doesn't really rock as a sentence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the energy released from U235 fission according to ENDF/B-VII.1 (which is the gold standard of data)

```
   Quantity                                Value(MeV)  Uncertainty
 Kinetic energy of the fragments          169.130000    0.490000
 Kinetic energy of the prompt neutrons      4.916000    0.070000
 Kinetic energy of the delayed neutrons     0.007400    0.001110
 Kinetic energy of the prompt gammas        6.600000    0.500000
 Kinetic energy of the delayed gammas       6.330000    0.050000
 Total energy released by delayed betas     6.500000    0.050000
 Energy carried away by the neutrinos       8.750000    0.070000
 Total energy less neutrino energy        193.483400    0.150000
 Total energy release per fission (sum)   202.233400    0.130000
```

I think the number that is giving you the most problems is the average binding energy of the fission products.  This number is going to vary quite a bit depending on what the fission products are and how many neutrons are released per fission.  I would take 8.5 as a "rough" number.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission) says 202.79 MeV, with reference to [Kopeikin *et al*. (2004)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0410100.pdf). That is calculated. Part of this energy is neutrinos that fly away.

In Table 4, the thermal fission energy in a PWR reactor is a bit less, 201.9 MeV.

Comment: thank you. But why is it incompatible with 235 x (8.5 MeV -7.59 MeV)=213 MeV ?

Comment: That is not incompatible.

Comment: 213 MeV is not equal to 201.9 MeV.

Comment: But $235 \times 0.9$ is compatible with anything between 200 MeV and 225 MeV.

Comment: But there should be only one "average" value. The average value for binding energy of energy of uranium is 7.59 MeV. The average value of binding energy of decay products is 8.5 MeV. Thus, the average of energy release is 235 * (8.5 - 7.59 )=213 : this is not compatible with 201.9. So where is my mistake ?

Comment: I believe that the only solution is that 8.5 MeV is *not* the average value of binding energy of decay product : it would be the *position of the maximum* of the distribution. Do you agree ?